# Excessive thread count yields better results with file reading

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, unix, io

I have a hundred million files, my program reads all these files at every startup. I have been looking for ways to make this process faster. On the way, I've encountered something strange. My CPU has 4 physical cores, but reading this many files with even higher thread counts yields much better results. Which is interesting, given that opening threads more than the logical core count of the CPU should be somewhat pointless.

```
8     Threads: 29.858 s
16    Threads: 15.882 s
32    Threads: 9.989 s
64    Threads: 7.965 s
128   Threads: 8.275 s
256   Threads: 8.159 s
512   Threads: 8.098 s
1024  Threads: 8.253 s
4096  Threads: 8.744 s
16001 Threads: 10.033 s
```

Why this may occur ? Is it some disk bottleneck ?

- Did the homework, profiled the code, literally %95 of the runtime consists of `read()`, `open()` and `close()`
- I am reading the first 4096 bytes of every file (my pagesize)
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Intel i7 6700HQ
- Samsung 970 Evo Plus NVMe SSD
- GCC/G++ 11

Comment: *opening threads more than the logical core count of the CPU should be somewhat pointless*. Why? It makes sense to have more IO bound threads than the number of cores.

Comment: Unexplainable without more details. Do you create all  your threads just in time, or all up front? My guess is that the best solution is to have a threadpool with std::thread::harware_concurrency() number of threads and schedule the work in that. But without measurements it is impossible to tell. So my advice : start to profile and find the  bottlenecks on your system.

Comment: @kaylum It's just that, the online research I've done, even in SO, nobody mentions these possible benefits. `opening threads more than the logical core count of the CPU should be somewhat pointless`, This wasn't my first thought, but people's claims got me thinking.

Comment: @PepijnKramer All threads start together (divide the files between them), all do the work together, all finish together. Collect the data they gathered.

Comment: @Max I think "opening threads more than the logical core count of the CPU should be somewhat pointless" is right only when your task is bound on CPU.

Comment: @Nimrod But then, when in another platform, where there are many disks and many more processors, how can one decide the optimal settings. The trial and error cost has increased.

Comment: Welcome to the world of system engineering. Nobody said life is easy. Tuning for performance is one of those non-trivial tasks.

Comment: @MaxPaython Welcome to multithreading! Nothing makes sense. The number threads which is optimal is the number of CPU cores only when the threads are running without any synchronisation or waiting. Think about it, (assuming a 4 core CPU)when a thread waits, the optimal number becomes 5. This is at least what I've understood. Just add a lot more noise to this and you get confusion. Testing is the only way.

Comment: @Max aha, optimizing is not a simple job. You have to tune under different envs

Comment: If you have a hundred million files that you read every time the program starts it sounds like you should reorganize your data. If the files aren't updated between every run, extract the data you need and package it in a smaller file. If the data is updated between runs, why not use a database?

Comment: "_how can one decide the optimal settings_" - I wouldn't try. I would use a parallel execution policy and let the implementation spin as many threads as it sees fit. What are you doing with these one hundred million 4096 B blocks?

Comment: @ShambhavGautam That's also not true, multithreading does makes sense, otherwise computers wouldn't have them. It is a tool however that you need to learn how to understand. Hence measure, find your bottlenecks and adapt.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was thinking the same, OP is definitly trading memory against speed here up to the point where I suspect swapping may start to occur.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I can't organize the files, I don't create them. However, I did implement a solution of not requiring to read all the files all the time. But this time (the question), I am just improving the first part, which reading all the files.

Comment: Ok, and what do you do with the one hundred million 4096 B blocks?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I extract some info, contained in the first 4096 bytes of all these files. These files are being deleted and added all the time (server cache files, nginx). As I said, I already did what you said, I store the information in these files, to not read all of them again. But sometimes I have to, and just optimizing that part for now.

Comment: @MaxPaython Sure, I just wanted to know a little more to see if I could put something together based on execution policies that you could try out.

Comment: Btw, how are the files ordered in the directory structure? Are all in one directory or based on some hash (like in git)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Uniformly distributed among nested folders like disk/1/3/0a/file

Comment: If you do not care about using OS-specific functions for the sake for performance, note that Linux added recently functions to open+read+close a file in one system call. System calls are very expensive so I should help for such a case. Additionally, you might be interested in IO-Uring which is a system call interface for storage device *asynchronous* I/O. This interface help to avoid many system call and has been proven to be very efficient recently. I think it should read a much higher performance with only few threads.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I was exploring async IO, it is interesting, but may make me change the structure of my proejct a bit, given that all of it is designed on sync IO. This ``open+read+close``, I will look into.

Answer (score 4):

> Why this may occur ?

If you open one file at "`/a/b/c/d/e`" then read one block of data from the file; the OS may have to fetch directory info for "`/a`", then fetch directory info for "`/a/b`", then fetch directory info for "`/a/b/c`", then... It might add up to a total of 6 blocks fetched from disk (5 blocks of directory info then one block of file data), and those blocks might be scattered all over the disk.

If you open a 100 million files and read one block of file data from each; then this might involve fetching 600 million things (500 million pieces of directory info, and 100 million pieces of file data).

What is the optimal order to do these 600 million things?

Often there's directory info caches and file data caches involved (and all requests that can be satisfied by data that's already cached should be done ASAP, before that data is evicted out of cache/s to make room for other data). Often the disk hardware also has rules (e.g. faster to access all blocks within the same "group of disk blocks" before switching to the next "group of disk blocks"). Sometimes there's parallelism in the disk hardware (e.g. two requests from the same zone can't be done in parallel, but 2 requests from different zones can be done in parallel).

The optimal order to do these 600 million things is something the OS can figure out.

More specifically; the optimal order to do these 600 million things is something the OS can figure out; **if and only if the OS actually knows about all of them**.

If you have (e.g.) 8 threads that send one request (e.g. to open a file) and then block (using no CPU time) until the pending request completes; then the OS will only know about a maximum of 8 requests at a time. In other words; the operating system's ability to optimize the order that file IO requests are performed is constrained by the number of pending requests, which is constrained by the number of threads you have.

Ideally; a single thread would be able to ask the OS "open all the files in this list of a hundred million files" so that the OS can fully optimize the order (with the least thread management overhead). Sadly, most operating systems don't support anything like this (e.g. POSIX asynchronous IO fails to support any kind of "asynchronous open").

Having a large number of threads (that are all blocked and not using any CPU time while they wait for their request/s to actually be done by file system and/or disk driver) is the only way to improve the operating system's ability to optimize the order of IO requests.